# How to achieve hard-code voilations with CodePro?

Tags: checkstyle, findbugs, pmd, codepro

I have to check some voilations like this

```
if(emp.companyName="MyCompany")
```

ie. Here there should not "MyComapany" hard-code in expression or condition checking.

which rule of CodePro do this.

Answer (score 1):

PMD has a rule for similar problems that you described:

[AvoidDuplicateLiterals](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.2.1/pmd-java/rules/java/strings.html#AvoidDuplicateLiterals) - Code containing duplicate String literals can usually be improved by declaring the String as a constant field.